# how to check null value in retrofit

Tags: android, null, retrofit

I am using Picasso for loading the image in my application. I am getting null value for image from service. How to handle the null value.

my code:

```
if(reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl().isEmpty() || reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl() == null){
               Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.profile)
                       .into(viewHolder.user_image);
            }else if(reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl() != null){
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile)
                    .into(viewHolder.user_image);}
```

error:

```
10-04 08:42:43.653 23300-23300/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.restosapp.restoss, PID: 23300
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
        at .listing.DetailpageActivtiy$Reviewpageadapter.onBindViewHolder(DetailpageActivtiy.java:1198)
        at cooss.listing.DetailpageActivtiy$Reviewpageadapter.onBindViewHolder(DetailpageActivtiy.java:1172)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535155/changing-a-textview-text-color-in-a-dynamic-layout?noredirect=1#comment92035607_52535155

Answer (score 3):

First priority If a condition is true then do something like this following:

```
if(reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl()!=null && !reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl().isEmpty())
{

  Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile)
                .into(viewHolder.user_image);}
}
else 
{
 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.profile)
                   .into(viewHolder.user_image);
}
```

It'll solve your problem

Comment: tank you Rakesh:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535155/changing-a-textview-text-color-in-a-dynamic-layout?noredirect=1#comment92035607_52535155

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition order in `if`

```
if(reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl() == null || reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl().isEmpty() )
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this:**
>
> ```
>  public boolean isEmpty(String s) {
>                return s.trim().equals("") || s == null || s.isEmpty() || s.equals("null");
>        }
> ```

```
if(!isEmpty(reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl())){
 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile)
                    .into(viewHolder.user_image);
}
else{
 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.profile)
                       .into(viewHolder.user_image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No need to check null values** using Picasso. Picasso is smart enough, it will handle null values.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(viewHolder.user_image);}
```

If URL is null or empty, it will show `placeholder` image.

Comment: If `reviewdata.get(position).user.getPhotoUrl()` is empty or blank then It will definitely raise exception 

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:297)
        at`

Comment: @RakeshKumar Thanks for this, but you should test it yourself. I tested it with 2.5.2 version.

Comment: I have tested it and getting an above exception used this version `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2`

Comment: Did you set placeholder?

Comment: Yes, I have used placeholder like this `Picasso.with(getActivity())
                            .load(client_JobImage)
                            .fit()
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.image_chat)
                            .into(iv_choose);`

Where 'client_JobImage` is URL of the image and `iv_choose` is imageView

Comment: I also tested it like same I pasted. I'll test it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181298/discussion-between-rakesh-kumar-and-khemraj).